# Simply uploading a file to google compute

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to upload a file to the disk attached to my google compute vm from my local machine.

```
abhigenie92_gmail_com@instance-1:~$ pwd
/home/abhigenie92_gmail_com
abhigenie92_gmail_com@instance-1:~$ gcloud compute copy-files C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Feb\Model\MixedCrowds28 Runge kutta 2nd order try.nl
ogo: ./


abhigenie92_gmail_com@instance-1:~$ gcloud compute copy-files C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Feb\Model\MixedCrowds28 Runge kutta 2nd order try.nl
ogo: /home/abhigenie92_gmail_com
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) All sources must be
```

**edit2:** Get the following error now:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RE: edit2

Since gcloud's copy-files is a custom implementation of scp, you need to specify the complete path on your VM where you want to copy the files to. In your specific case:

LOCAL-FILE-PATH> gcloud compute copy-files [FILENAMES] [VM-NAME]:[FULL-REMOTE-PATH]

In your specific example:

C:\Users\sony\Desktop> gcloud compute copy-files copy.nlogo instance-1:/home/abhigenie92_gmail_com/

This command will then place the file(s) into your user's home directory root. Just make sure the remote path exists, and that you user has write rights to the destination.

Comment: I still get the error "All sources must be local files when the destination is remote."

Comment: I've adjusted the command string: Win path work-around by going to the source file directory prior to issuing the gcloud command

Comment: Can you also specify how would achieve the other way round that is copying files from the google compute instance to local machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of what you posted, you're trying to copy things from your local machine to a cloud instance from inside the instance. I'm afraid you can't do that.

I take it you have already installed the [gcloud compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#install) tool? If not, install that on your local machine (follow the link) and open up the windows command line, type `gcloud auth login` to authenticate, then you should be able to do what you want to with the following command:

```
gcloud compute copy-files C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Feb\Model\MixedCrowds28\ Runge\ kutta\ 2nd\ order\ try.nlogo  <VM Name>:~/
```

Note that I have escaped the spaces in your filename - it's a good idea to get out of the habit of spaces in filenames - and made a couple of assumptions:

- Your VM is running linux
- You are okay with copying up to your home directory on the VM

If any of these assumptions is incorrect, you may have problems. To copy somewhere else, change the path in the `<VM Name>:~/` part

---

Edit: I mangled a file extension in the original, fixed now!

Comment: Thanks. But , .nlogo is an extension, where do I specify the vm name?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Ha, sorry about that. The VM name is the last argument, so you would replace the 'ogo' bit with the name. I have edited the answer, hopefully you can see what to do now

Comment: Please the above edit. I am aware about the error being new to this.

Comment: You can make that go away using `gcloud compute config` I think. Have a look at the documentation for gcloud compute: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#auth
(see step 4. under auth)

Comment: Thanks! But I still have an error . Please check the edit above.

Comment: Does the file copy.nlogo exist? That's different to the commands you were posting before.

Comment: Yeah I renamed to avoid space as you had suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70573/discussion-between-theolodus-and-abhishek-bhatia).